# laravel polymorphic relation custom type

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an Image table as follow:

```
Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('path');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('imageable_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('imageable_type')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('image_properties_id')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
});
```

I want to have polymorphic relation with images table and it works fine for most parts however the problem here is that some Models such as Post can have images for different purpose, for instance a post can have a image for post's cover and also images used in the post content.
Is it possible to access  only images belonging to post's cover and not content?

I know that I can define custom type using morphmap, but is it possible to define two different types that points to the same Model and use these type to filter the results?

Comment: how are you planning to store `type` information for any image of given Post?

Comment: "imageable_type" is result of concatenating model name and use case of the image. Several examples for "imageable_type" are: "post/content" or "post/cover"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extended relationship to filter out as required.

Assuming you have `images` relationship on `Post` model, you can create two more as follows (one each for content and cover)

```php
public function coverImages() {
    return $this->images()->where('imageable_type', 'post/cover');
}

public function contentImages() {
    return $this->images()->where('imageable_type', 'post/content');
}
```

With those relationships definition, now you can use each of them as an independent eloquent relationship.

Comment: as those relationships are having string `post` on imageable_type it might not be useful for other models. For all those models to work, you can remove the `post/` prefix from the image type.

Comment: How `images` relationship should be define? is it a polymorphic relation?

Comment: define `images` as a normal polymorphic relation as suggested by Laravel.

`public function images() { return $this->morphMany(Image::class, 'imageable'); }`